Tabulate a column in data.frame ignoring the order of elements in it in R
In my DATA below, I wonder how to table() the variable lang_comb ignoring the order?
For example, "english  spanish  french" and "french   english  spanish" are to be considered the same.
Is there a way to tabulate variable lang_comb this way in R?
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(header=T, text="
ID  lang1    lang2    lang3
1   spanish  english  NA
2   english  spanish  french
3   russian  english  NA
4   french   english  spanish
5   english  russian  NA
6   english  french   NA")


combs <- DATA %>% 
  mutate(lang_comb = paste(lang1, lang2, lang3, sep=","))

with(combs, table(lang_comb))


     english,french,NA     english,russian,NA english,spanish,french french,english,spanish     russian,english,NA 
                     1                      1                      1                      1                      1 
    spanish,english,NA 
                     1 


If you sort then collapse your data then order won't matter (because they'll be in the same order):
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DATA |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(lang = str_flatten_comma(sort(c_across(starts_with("lang"))))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  count(lang)
#   lang                         n
#   <chr>                    <int>
# 1 english, french              1
# 2 english, french, spanish     2
# 3 english, russian             2
# 4 english, spanish             1

Or if you want to use table() you can pipe the output of the mutate statement to pull(lang) |> table().

Here's a variation using reshaping first:
library(tidyverse)
DATA |>
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_drop_na = TRUE) |>
  arrange(value) |>
  summarize(lang = paste(value, collapse = ", "), .by = ID) |>
  count(lang)

Result
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  lang                         n
  <chr>                    <int>
1 english, french              1
2 english, french, spanish     2
3 english, russian             2
4 english, spanish             1


You can try base R code with table like below
d <- table(unlist(DATA[-1]), row(DATA[-1]))>0
nms <- row.names(d)
stack(table(apply(d, 2, \(k) toString(nms[k]))))

which gives
  values ind                     
1 1      english, french         
2 2      english, french, spanish
3 2      english, russian        
4 1      english, spanish        


Using apply and sort
data.frame(table(apply(DATA[-1], 1, \(x) toString(sort(x)))))
                      Var1 Freq
1          english, french    1
2 english, french, spanish    2
3         english, russian    2
4         english, spanish    1

Note, if you want NAs to show up use sort(x, na.last=T)
